# org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process Error parsing HTTP request header

Tags: ssl, tomcat7, tomcat8

24-Oct-2013 21:53:05.288 INFO [http-apr-8443-exec-3] org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.
24-Oct-2013 21:53:05.288 INFO [http-apr-8443-exec-4] org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process Error parsing HTTP request header
 Note: further occurrences of HTTP header parsing errors will be logged at DEBUG level.

I am getting the above error when using HTTPS configuration in Tomcat 8.0 0r Tomcat 7.

Please help. My tomcat HTTPS configuration goes like this.....

```
  <Connector
   className="org.apache.coyote.tomcat4.CoyoteConnector"
   port="8443" 
   enableLookups="false"
   acceptCount="10"
   connectionTimeout="60000" 
    scheme="https" secure="true" >
 <Factory
   className="org.apache.coyote.tomcat4.CoyoteServerSocketFactory"
          clientAuth="false" protocol="TLS"
          keystoreFile="D:\Samplekey.key" keystorePass="PASSWORD" />
 </Connector>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your configuration is from Tomcat 4 but the error message has to be from at least Tomcat 7. The chances of Tomcat 4 SSL configuration working in Tomcat 7 are zero. Follow the Tomcat docs and correctly configure SSL for which ever version of Tomcat you are using.